# Angular: HTTPClient - conversion of nested enum

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have `StructureInterface` like

```
export interface StructureInterface {
  items: Array<string>;
  status: VersionStatus;
}
export enum VersionStatus {
  NEW, OLD, CHANGED
}
```

When I send a request like

```
this.http.get<StructureInterface>(`myURL`);
```

the `status` is always interpreted as `string` and not as an enum type. This has servere consequences with comparing and checking.

How to get `status` as enum and as `string`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 typescript parsing enum interface attribute in response object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539033/angular-4-typescript-parsing-enum-interface-attribute-in-response-object)

Comment: Not really cause for the HTML templates it would be beneficial to have them as enum and not as strings.

Comment: [yes..."If you're using typescript 2.4 or above"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539095/542251)

Answer (score 1):

One needs to convert the string manually into an enum and since Typescript is little bit picky I found the solution with TS3.9 (?)

```
this.http.get<StructureInterface>(`myURL`).pipe(
  map((item:StructureInterface) => {
       item.status = VersionStatus[item.status as unknown as keyof typeof VersionStatus];
       return item;
}));
```

So, that's a manual conversion which is not done automatically :-/

**UPDATE**
Although I succeeded in the conversion I failed in regard of sending an `enum`. Since Angular use the `enum` as a field within a string array for HTTP requests the value of the `enum` it is sent out as id, i.e. `1` instead of `OLD`.

Therefore I decided to use normal `string` since this saves a lot of time :-/